# How to determine if an EventLog already exists

Tags: powershell, event-log, eventlog-source

I'm using the following line to create a new event log

```
new-eventlog -LogName "Visual Studio Builds" -Source "Visual Studio"
```

I want to run this every time, because if I run a build from a new computer, I'd still like to see the event logs.

The problem is that every time the script is run after the log is already created, it throws an error.

```
New-EventLog : The "Visual Studio" source is already registered on the "localhost" computer.
At E:\Projects\MyApp\bootstrap.ps1:14 char:13
+ new-eventlog <<<<  -LogName "Visual Studio Builds" -Source "Visual Studio"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewEventLogCommand
```

Now I know that I can "search" for the event log

```
Get-EventLog -list | Where-Object {$_.logdisplayname -eq "Visual Studio Builds"}
```

But now how do I determine if it exists?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430620/only-pass-parameter-if-value-supplied - I've posted sample code for a wrapper method (though currently there's a bug - hence posting here)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So I was on the right path with `Get-EventLog`.

Instead of just reading it, I stored it in a variable. Then I checked if the variable was `null`.

This has achieved what I was looking to do.

```
$logFileExists = Get-EventLog -list | Where-Object {$_.logdisplayname -eq "Visual Studio Builds"} 
if (! $logFileExists) {
    New-EventLog -LogName "Visual Studio Builds" -Source "Visual Studio"
}
```

Comment: NB: Only works if the event log/source has been written to; if it was created but not written to you'll gen an "already exists" exception.

Answer (score 63):

```
# Check if Log exists
# Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.exists(v=vs.110).aspx
[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::Exists('Application');


# Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.sourceexists(v=vs.110).aspx
# Check if Source exists
[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists("YourLogSource");
```

Comment: This answer is the most complete in terms of checking whether both a log and/or source exist. It's important to remember that using Get-EventLog and filtering/searching from there depends on the fact that an event has been written to the target log in order for it to show up.

Comment: VERY CLEAN!  Nice one-liner.

Comment: Thanks.  You can even take off the 'system.'.

Answer (score 22):

```
if ([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists("Visual Studio") -eq $False) {
    New-EventLog -LogName "Visual Studio Builds" -Source "Visual Studio"
}
```

Comment: We expect answer to be a little bit more verbose. Teaching how to fish is better than just spoon feed the OP.

Comment: Brilliant!  this is the only answer that actually checks if the source value exists & doesnt resort to scanning the event log.

Comment: Note that this script will require local admin rights to work. Otherwise some eventlogs - such as securty - can't be accessed, resulting in a exception. The exception is thrown in both cases (true and false), so you can't determine if the log exists by catching.

Answer (score 14):

Check the `Exists` method:

```
[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::Exists('Visual Studio Builds')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it next time I get a chance.

Answer (score 3):

To simply check if exists:

```
$EventLogName = "LogName"
if ( !($(Get-EventLog -List).Log.Contains($EventLogName)))
{}
```

But to create the new one you'll need "As Administrator" privilege. To solve this I used to call a subprocess:

```
Start-Process -verb runAs powershell.exe  -ArgumentList "-file $PSScriptRoot\CreateLog.ps1" -wait
```

With simple CreateLog.ps1:

```
New-EventLog -LogName ScriptCheck -Source ScriptCheck
Write-EventLog –LogName ScriptCheck `
–Source ScriptCheck –EntryType Information –EventID 100 `
–Message "Start logging!"
```

Comment: This is valid, thanks. When it comes to Admin, I do a bit different approach, I [Assert that they are Admin](https://github.com/FutureStateMobile/poshBAR/blob/master/src/poshBAR/Test-RunAsAdmin.ps1), and throw an exception if not. This forces the script to be run in an admin console before it starts.

Comment: my approach is mostly intended to be used in a scheduler :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Get-/Test-EventLogSource

The `System.Diagnostics` methods are limiting. There can be only one source on a computer. Different computers may have the same source, but in different logs. In my experience you start running into issues after working with these methods and creating/removing logs and sources. I wrote the following to verify my custom log/source.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

function Get-EventLogSource {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string]$LogFile = '*',
        [string]$Source = '*'
    )

    Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_NTEventLOgFile -Verbose:$false | ForEach-Object {

        $_logName = $PSItem.FileName
 
        $PSItem.Sources | ForEach-Object {
 
            $oResult = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
                Source  = $PSItem
                LogName = $_logName
            } | Select-Object  -Property Source, LogName

            Write-Output $oResult
        }
    } | Sort-Object -Property Source | Where-Object { $PSItem.Source -like $Source -and $PSItem.LogName -like $LogFile }    
}

function Test-EventLogSource {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string]$LogFile = '*',
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Source
    )
    $_result = Get-EventLogSource -LogFile $LogFile -Source $Source
    return ($null -ne $_result)
}

Clear-Host

#Test-EventLogSource -LogFile 'System' -Source '.NET*' -Verbose
#Test-EventLogSource -LogFile 'Application' -Source '.NET*' -Verbose
#Test-EventLogSource -LogFile 'dummy' -Source '.NET*' -Verbose
#Test-EventLogSource -LogFile '*' -Source '.NET*' -Verbose
#Test-EventLogSource -Source '.NET*' -Verbose

#Test-EventLogSource -LogFile 'Application' -Source 'vs' -Verbose
#Test-EventLogSource -LogFile '*' -Source 'vss' -Verbose

#Test-EventLogSource -Source '*power*'


#Get-EventLogSource
#Get-EventLogSource -LogFile 'System' -Source '.NET*' -Verbose | Format-Table
#Get-EventLogSource -LogFile 'Application' -Source '.NET*' -Verbose | Format-Table
#Get-EventLogSource -LogFile 'dummy' -Source '.NET*' -Verbose | Format-Table
#Get-EventLogSource -LogFile '*' -Source '.NET*' -Verbose | Format-Table
#Get-EventLogSource -Source '.NET*' -Verbose | Format-Table

#Get-EventLogSource -LogFile 'Application' -Source 'vs' -Verbose | Format-Table
#Get-EventLogSource -LogFile '*' -Source 'vss' -Verbose | Format-Table

#Get-EventLogSource -Source '*power*'| Format-Table
```

#### Using Get-WinEvent

```
Get-WinEvent -ListProvider * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-Object -Property Name -ExpandProperty LogLinks | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, LogName |
    Sort-Object -Property Name
```

Comment: Surprised this hasn't got more votes - it's the only way I've found to code a test for the source without getting a warning about not accessing the Security logs if you;re not admin.

Answer (score 2):

I think below approach could reduce the workload of filter with `where`

```
    try
    {
        Get-EventLog -LogName "Visual Studio Builds" -ErrorAction Ignore| Out-Null
    }
    catch {
        New-EventLog -LogName "Visual Studio Builds" -Source "Visual Studio"
    }
```

Comment: on an application with heavy workload, yes you want to optimize filtering clauses... for a script... not that much. try/catch feels icky.

Comment: Chase is correct, you simply don't ever want to use exception handling as part of your logic. Jonathan Donahue's answer is the most complete in terms of checking whether both a log and/or source exist.

Answer (score 2):

Less complex:

```
 if (!(Get-Eventlog -LogName "Application" -Source "YourLog")){
      New-Eventlog -LogName "Application" -Source "YourLog"
 }
```

Comment: Contrary to *all* intuition, [`Get-EventLog`](http://ss64.com/ps/get-eventlog.html) does **not** have a `-Source` parameter. Sorry, but -1.

Comment: @jpmc26 `Get-EventLog` has indeed a `-Source` parameter. (See [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog)). However the proposed solution is listing actual events in the event log, so -1.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me. Hope it helps somebody.

```
$EventLog = "SLAPS"
If ([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists("$EventLog") -eq $false) {
    New-EventLog -LogName "SLAPS_PasswordRotation" -Source "$EventLog"
    Write-EventLog -LogName "SLAPS_PasswordRotation" -Source "$EventLog" -Message "EventLog Succesfully Created" -EventId 10000 -EntryType SuccessAudit
}
Else {
    Write-EventLog -LogName "SLAPS_PasswordRotation" -Source "$EventLog" -Message "New Rotation Started Succesfully" -EventId 1 -EntryType SuccessAudit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$SourceExists = [System.Diagnostics.Eventlog]::SourceExists("XYZ")
if($SourceExists -eq $false){
    [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource("XYZ", "Application")
}
```

Just doing this is not enough. Even though you've created the event source, `$SourceExists` will always be `false`. I tested it also by running `CreateEventSource` then `Remove-EventLog`, and removing it failed. After creating an event source, you must write something to it. Append this after running `CreateEventSource`.

```
Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "XYZ" -EventID 0 -EntryType Information -Message "XYZ source has been created."
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/361842/johnlbevan pointing this out (in the comments).