# Only pass parameter if value supplied

Tags: powershell, parameters, optional-parameters, powershell-4.0

**Background**

I've created a wrapper function around `Write-EventLog` so that I can easily call it without having to concern myself with checking for & creating an event log/source each time.  By simply adding a `-Force` parameter, I want it to create the log if it doesn't exist; if I don't add that parameter it should behave as normal (which reduces overhead of multiple checks if called from code where I know that log will exist).

I've copied the list of parameters available to `write-eventlog` such that I have the full functionality available to my wrapper.  However; if I don't supply values to some of these parameters (e.g. RawData), they default to null; then I end up trying to pass null for this parameter; which is different to not supplying it.  I don't want to have to list every possible iteration of parameter combinations with checks for whether those values were supplied before calling the appropriate method signature.

**Question**

Is there a way to only pass values to parameters of `write-eventlog` where those parameters had been passed to `write-eventlog2`?

**Code**

```
cls
$myLog = 'Application'
$mySource = 'My PS Script'
$myEventId = 1 
[System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]$myEntryType = [System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]::Error 
$myMessage = 'This is a test message'

function Write-EventLog2
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(  
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String]$LogName
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String]$Source
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=3,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Int32]$EventId
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=4,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]$EntryType = [System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]::Information
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=5,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String]$Message
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=6,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Int16]$Category = 1
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=7,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=8,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Byte[]]$RawData
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=9,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [switch]$Force 
    )

    begin
    {
        if($Force.IsPresent)
        {
            if (! ([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::Exists($LogName) -and [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($Source) )) 
            {
                New-EventLog -LogName $LogName -Source $Source 
            }
        }
    }
    process {
        Write-EventLog -LogName $LogName -Source $Source -EventId $EventId -EntryType $EntryType -Message $Message -Category $Category -ComputerName $ComputerName -RawData $RawData
    }
    #end{} #no ending actions required
}

Write-EventLog2 $myLog $mySource $myEventId $myEntryType $myMessage -Force
```

**Error**

```
Write-EventLog : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'RawData'. 
The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not 
null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:51 char:167
```

Comment: ps. Another option is Splatting, as shown here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80154/write-to-the-event-log-without-needing-to-check-whether-or-not-it-exists-by-use

Comment: My question was pretty similar to yours.  Check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35773596/288393

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would consider [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) for something like this as you could account for null / empty without changing too much of the code.

```
begin
    {
        if($Force.IsPresent)
        {
            if (! ([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::Exists($LogName) -and [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($Source) )) 
            {
                New-EventLog -LogName $LogName -Source $Source 
            }
        }

        if($rawdata){
            $rawdataparameter = @{
                RawData = $rawdata 
            }
        }

    }
    process {
        Write-EventLog -LogName $LogName -Source $Source -EventId $EventId -EntryType $EntryType -Message $Message -Category $Category -ComputerName $ComputerName @RawDataParameter
    }
```

Conditionally build a small hashtable that contains the parameter by name and the value. The use the at sign varialbe notation to splat the `Write-Log` command. In practice, with `Get-ChildItem`, if the table contains no pairs or is null it is ignored.

Comment: Thanks; good solution, but am not yet marking as selected answer as I'm hoping a more elegant solution will crop up. . .

Comment: ps. this just led me to discover something - `Remove-Variable`; I hadn't realised that a variable not existing was valid but different to null.  `if($RawData -eq $null) {Remove-Variable RawData};` or `if(!$RawData) {Remove-Variable RawData};` seem to work well.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Matt for leading me to realise an unassigned/declared variable is different to null, which led me to the discovery of `Remove-Variable`.

http://ss64.com/ps/remove-variable.html

This changes a variable from simply having the value `$null` to not existing; and thus not being passed even when listed as passed.

```
cls
$myLog = 'Application'
$mySource = 'My PS Script'
$myEventId = 1 
[System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]$myEntryType = [System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]::Error 
$myMessage = 'This is a test message'

function Write-EventLog2
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(  
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String]$LogName
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String]$Source
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=3,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Int32]$EventId
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=4,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]$EntryType
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=5,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String]$Message
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=6,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Int16]$Category 
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=7,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String]$ComputerName 
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=8,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Byte[]]$RawData
        ,
        [Parameter(Position=9,Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [switch]$Force 
    )

    begin
    {
        if($Force.IsPresent)
        {
            if (! ([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::Exists($LogName) -and [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($Source) )) 
            {
                New-EventLog -LogName $LogName -Source $Source 
            }
        }
    }
    process {
        if(!$EntryType) {Remove-Variable EntryType};
        if(!$Message) {Remove-Variable Message};
        if(!$Category) {Remove-Variable Category};
        if(!$ComputerName) {Remove-Variable ComputerName};
        if(!$RawData) {Remove-Variable RawData};
        Write-EventLog -LogName $LogName -Source $Source -EventId $EventId -EntryType $EntryType -Message $Message #-Category $Category -ComputerName $ComputerName -RawData $RawData
    }
    #end{} #no ending actions required
}

Write-EventLog2 $myLog $mySource $myEventId $myEntryType $myMessage -Force
```