# PowerShell: Forwarding parameters to Commandlet

Tags: powershell

We cannot import a string containing csv using the variable drive:

```
Import-Csv Variable:\myCsvVariable
```

Therefore I wrote a simple function which does the same thing:

```
Function Import-CsvString {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string[]]$CsvContent,
        [char]$Delimiter
    )

    if ($input) {
        $CsvContent = $input;
    } 

    $temp = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

    ($CsvContent | Out-String) | Set-Content -Path $temp;

    $m = Import-Csv -Path $temp -Delimiter $Delimiter

    Remove-Item $temp -Force

    $m;
}
```

Is it possible to pass the non-specifying of `Delimiter` to `Import-Csv` (or any other command)?

I KNOW that you can easily do an `if...then...else` on whether `Delimiter` is not null, and call `Import-Csv` with or without `Delimiter`, but that is not what I am asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This answer (and question) is about forwarding parameters, not about CSV.**

I looked at "splatting" and there is a method of passing all the incoming parameters, which will be contained in `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable, to another commandlet.

We first add `Path` argument and remove `CsvContent` argument:

```
Function Import-CsvString {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string[]]$CsvContent,
        [char]$Delimiter
    )

    if ($input) {
        $CsvContent = $input;
    } 

    $temp = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

    ($CsvContent | Out-String) | Set-Content -Path $temp;

    $args = $PSBoundParameters + @{ Path = $temp };
    $args.Remove('CsvContent');

    $m = Import-Csv @args

    Remove-Item $temp -Force

    $m;
}
```

**References:**

- [about_Splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx)
- [briantist - splatting-psboundparameters-default-values-optional-parameters](https://www.briantist.com/how-to/splatting-psboundparameters-default-values-optional-parameters/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want to do is converting from a csv string. Here is a sample:

```
$csv = "X,Y,Foo
10,20,super
30,40,simple"

ConvertFrom-Csv $csv
```

Will output

```
X  Y  Foo   
-  -  ---   
10 20 super 
30 40 simple
```

You don't have to mess with temp files

Comment: Thank you.  There are quite a lot of verbs in PowerShell and I did not know of this one.  I suppose next time I will do `get-command | ? { $_.Name -match '.*csv.* }` before reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You can simply call `gcm *csv*` :). You can get a list of vergs using `Get-Verb`. Hope that helps! Anyway, you ought to take a look at splatting arguments . this is a very powerful feature of POwerShell when dealing with argument logic.

Comment: Thanks, there are loads of features of PowerShell I don't know :)